# How to get an object by anchor text?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of links:

```
<a href="/111">AAAAA</a>
<a href="/222">BBBBB</a>
<a href="/333">CCCCC</a>
```

I would like to get object `$('a')` with the contents `BBBBB`, and in the next step I am going to do:

```
$(this).addClass('current');
```

How can I select the element with the `BBBBB` content?

Answer (score 4):

Use the `:contains` pseudo-class:

```
$('a:contains("BBBBB")')
```

[Here's a demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/nfNsf/)

Comment: Depending on the size of the page you are searching, first selecting the anchors and then filtering by the text content can be more performant, especially on mobile browsers or IE<9.

Comment: There is not a `contains` method on the jQuery object prototype. There is one on the root jQuery object, but it is used to test if one DOM element contains another.

Answer (score 3):

Using the `:contains` selector and hte `.filter` method:

```
$('a').filter(':contains("BBBBB")').addClass('current')
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it.

```
$("a:contains('BBBBB')").addClass('current');
```

From here:
http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/